# ionic2: horizontal avatars scroll inside a list

Tags: scroll, ionic2

I am working with `ionic2`, I have a list of items and each item holds an array of users:

```
<ion-list item-left>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items;">
      <ion-label>
        {{ item.name }}
      </ion-label>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

I am trying to add a horizontal avatars scroll to every item in the list

```
<ion-list item-left>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items;">
      <ion-label>
        {{ item.name }}
        <br> 
        <ion-scroll scrollx="true" style="height: 50px;">
          <ion-avatar *ngFor="let user of getAllUsers(item)">
            <img src="{{ user.avatar }}" style="max-width:2.5rem;max-height:2.5rem;">
          </ion-avatar>
        </ion-scroll>
      </ion-label>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Before I added `style="height: 50px;"` to `ion-scroll` nothing changed. After this addition the avatars are here but they are one bellow the other and not in a one row (and of course without horizontal scrolling).

How can I fix that?

P.S
Is it possible to add `width` to the scroller? I don't want it to take the whole page width.

Comment: Did you manage to get this to work?